# How to implement delegate/protocol(on iOS) in JNI on Android?

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, aar

I’m building an aar library on Android, which is with JNI/C++ codes. What I want to do is to pass an event (when the event happens, I want to pass it out) form C++ to Java application( the application which imports my aar library), and the application can then take care of the event.
I’ve done the same thing on iOS with delegate/protocol, is there any equivalent that I can implement on JNI for the same purpose? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure exactly what features of iOS delegate you want, but there are a lot of ways to get events out of C++ and into Java via JNI.  For example:

- Pass a "handler" object from Java to C++, and have C++ call its "handleEvent()" method when something happens.
- Create a ConcurrentQueue and have a C++ thread put event objects into it while the Java thread blocks waiting for events to happen